# ld cannot find -lQt5Multimedia

Tags: linux-mint, make, qt

I'm trying to build [BBQScreen](https://github.com/frankandrobot/bbqscreen_client) for Linux. During the make process, I get the following error:

```
g++ -m64 -o Linux/BBQScreenClient2 debug/main.o debug/mainwindow.o debug/screenform.o debug/QStreamDecoder.o debug/stdafx.o debug/ShrinkableQLabel.o debug/qrc_mainwindow.o debug/moc_screenform.o debug/moc_mainwindow.o debug/moc_QStreamDecoder.o debug/moc_ShrinkableQLabel.o   -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib -lavutil -lavcodec -lavformat -lswscale -lswresample -lz -lQt5OpenGL -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQt5Multimedia -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Network -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5Multimedia
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Linux/BBQScreenClient2] Error 1
```

But, `Qt5Multimedia` is installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libqt5multimedia5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libqt5multimedia5 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Any idea why this is occurring?

EDIT: I also have `qtmultimedia5-dev` installed.

Comment: The package being called `libqt5multimedia` doesn't necessarily imply it provides the right library. The Debian install instructions in `README.md` list the prerequisite packages. Have you got those?

Comment: @Anko I'm pretty sure I do. The first step is to `qmake`, and that was failing until I got all the prereqs met (at least from a Qt standpoint). Actually, I don't think `libqt5multimedia5` contained the right library, but I got some package installed that eventually filled the dependency to run `qmake`.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. If their published install-instructions fail for no obvious reason, it's probably time to contact the maintainer.

Comment: @Anko *sigh*. [This XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2213578) is the original thread for BBQScreen. It seems as though the project has been abandoned by the developer :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do it:

At first find `dpkg  -L libqt5multimedia5`

My lib found at `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` Then

add `-L /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` to your Makefile.

Then you you should add -`IYOURINCLUDEDIR` to Makefile

**MY UPDATE:**

DO IT:

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen# pkg-config --libs --cflags Qt5Multimedia
-I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/QtMultimedia -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/qt5 -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/QtNetwork -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/qt5 -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/qt5 -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/qt5 -lQt5Multimedia -lQt5Network -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core
```

Comment: add output of pkg-config to Makefile